# Reviewer doesn't know language of q/a, evaluates quality of answer; fails audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

Before I show the audit, I'm going to put a little example.

---

Let's say a question is posted asking to print something on the screen using C. I answer:

> To print something on the screen using C, use
>
> ```
>   printf
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>   printf ("Hello World");
> ```

What would you say to this answer (I'm not asking if it's correct or not)? I think that this is a good answer. It fits the rules of answering for SO, and isn't NAA, VLQ, Spam or Rude. I'm not saying whether it is correct or not, I'm just saying that it fits the rules for SO answers.

---

Now let's get to the point. I had [failed this review audit in the late answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12051262). The answer is:

> To generate compressed css file from saas by eclipse use
>
> ```
>   --output-style compressed
> ```
>
> Example
>
> `compile --sass-dir "${workspace_loc}/project-name/trunk/scss" --css-dir "${workspace_loc}/project-name/trunk/css" --images-dir "${workspace_loc}/project-name/trunk/images" --output-style compressed`

This answer is very similar to my example above. It matches the SO answering rules. Now it is deleted.

I was totally astonished seeing that this answer was deleted. I thought that there was something wrong, but then I pieced up something by seeing the comments. Still, I am not sure as I don't even know the basics of the programming language used in the q/a.

There were two comments, out of which one mattered more. It was:

> How does this add over the existing answer? No one is asking about Eclipse.

First thing; it was basically using the same thing which was in the accepted answer - `--style-compressed` (Believing the comment writer; don't know the code language)

Second thing; this question is not about eclipse, but the answer was. This makes the answer totally useless.

Seeing the above points, I think that this answer should be deleted. But shouldn't have been an audit. This is because the reviewer might not know the programming language of the q/a, and mostly will not check whether the answer is even using the same language as the question.

I thought that when we see an answer in one the the review queues, we should just pay specific attention to it; not whether it is correct, or plagiarism, or basically a copy-paste of another answer. You should see if it is fitting the answering rules of SO. Although, there is a slight difference from queue to queue.

To put this better, I'll provide an example:

---

A question is asked, which is tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). It is asking about printing characters on the screen.

Then, an answer is posted:

> Use `System.out.println`:
>
> ```
>    System.out.println ("These are some characters");
> ```

This answer is upvoted and accepted.

Another answer is posted:

> To print characters on the screen using C, use `printabc`:
>
> ```
>    printabc ("These are some characters");
> ```

This answer, as is not at all related to the question and wrong, is downvoted and finally deleted. Now while a user was reviewing posts, comes across the second deleted answer as an audit. The user does not know the basics of [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). When the user reads the answer, he / she must have thought that the question is also about [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) (not reviewers job to check if the question is also about [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)). As the user does not know C, they must have thought that this is the correct answer, and basically just continued, buy clicking the Looks OK / No Action needed button. They fail the audit.

---

Now in the example above, the reviewer was perfectly correct in their decision. Its not their mistake that they don't know C.

This example exactly applies to my case; I didn't know the programming language, I didn't check if the answer was using the same language as the question.

I think my action was correct, and this is a wrong audit. There was no way in which I could figure that this answer was wrong.

If someone thinks that I could have passed this audit, please post an answer and share your opinion.

Comment: IMO the right thing to do is to skip the question if you are not familiar with the programming language. Also use filter in all the review queues, where it is available(like close votes), to get questions about a familiar topic.

Comment: If you don't understand the answer, why do you attempt to review it?

Comment: 6 people voted to delete it [from review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11717156), which is strange. I have a feeling, judging by the timestamps, that everyone saw the generated comment and decided to vote without thinking. Terrible audit, though. Regardless of knowing the language, that *is* an answer. It's a *wrong* answer, but it *is an answer*.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen The queue isn't named the "incorrect answer" queue. It's to review *posts*. You don't need to know the language in detail to determine whether or not it is an answer (for almost all cases, including this one). The answer should *not* have been deleted from review. It *is* an answer.

Comment: @Rob Are you saying that if those reviewers had understood the answer, instead of just reading the comment, it wouldn't have been deleted in the first place?

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen I would imagine, yes. At least, if they are following the guide lines for deletion, which a wrong answer does not fulfill. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: Tbh thats definately an answer so thats a very unfortunate audit case.

Comment: It is an attempt at answering, and should be kept, downvote should be applied on the answer, but not deletion

Comment: @Ferry please read [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Vin: I agree, but the problem is that there is no filtration in the late answers queue. Even thought I know that [there is no shame in using skip](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip), I wouldn't do that as I mainly know C, and there are normally 1-2 questions about C in the late answers queue. I would then basically be performing no tasks, as I only know C.

Answer (score 4):

You voted "No action needed", which is incorrect.

If you look at the answer alone: it could at least use some capitalization, punctuation and formatting, which you did apply (at least a bit) to your examples. So you could have edited it.

Then if you look at the comments: they're right, the answer does not add anything that the existing answers don't already address. In fact, the answer tries to answer a different question altogether: *"How to compile and minify SASS to CSS in Eclipse?"*. In that case you should have downvoted or flagged.

So no, the action your voted on was not the correct one.

I don't know what the language has to do with this.